# Bitmap interpolation using bitmap class

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, interpolation, system.drawing

There is a grid, the grid size consists of 16*16 rows and columns. Each grid is filled with a color value. Now I want to have a smooth image/interpolated image (Please refer this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation. Please refer to this figure with the explanation (Example of bilinear interpolation on the unit square with the z-values 0, 1, 1 and 0.5 as indicated. Interpolated values in between represented by color.))

How do I achieve this using the bitmap class?

Comment: You want someone here to write an algorithm for you? Pass.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to indicate that you want to scale a color image up and use bilinear interpolation to create a smooth color gradient.

You have to create a new bitmap with the desired color depth and size. You also need to access the pixel colors of the old bitmap and use those values to modify the pixel colors of the new bitmp.

If you are not concerned about performance you can use [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) and [SetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx) to read and write individual pixels. You can also access the underlying bitmap data directly using [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx). This is more complicated and requires a deeper understanding of how pixels are stored in memory but can provide better performance when modifying the entire bitmap.

Comment: can be interpolation done keeping the bitmap size has 16*16; i mean original size has 16*16 and the destinatioin size has 16*16;

Comment: When you interpolate you compute values _between_ existing values. In terms of image processing you do this when you enlarge an image. You then have to interpolate the values of the new pixels introduced bewteen the existing pixels. If you want to modify the colors without changing the size of the image you probably want to perform a _convolution_ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). For instance you can blur the image to reduce any sharp shifts in color.